# Can get values ​from html5 or flash player? (baccarat bot)

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, selenium

I want to get values from baccarat (live casino) for bots.

Now I use c# to get colour of the results (Player, Tie, Banker for win/lose) and click automatically at the position that I set.

Other than C#, I'm trying with selenium, but I can't get XPath in flash player or html5.

Does anyone have ideas about how to do this?
What should I try?

For the test: Search "Sa Gaming" -> "Try Demo" (I don't tell gambling sites to promote or invite)

Thanks

Comment: You can't introspect FlashPlayer. With HTML5 you should be able without problems but maybe there are iframes objects in the page so you don't see actual page. The app is probably protected against bots.

Comment: @jcubic thanks for an answer.